# Can you place a cardinal number after a noun?

Tags: word-order, numbers

Is it possible to express a number of something by placing the cardinal after the noun?
I know the concept of postpositives, like `snow galore` etc. but does this apply to cardinals?
E.g. you can say `walking on four legs`, but would it be possible to say `walking on legs four`? Would it sound poetic/archaic or just plain wrong?

EDIT: After Andrew's comment - I am talking here about expressing the quantity of things. I.e. a situation, where there is a plural form of a noun and then a cardinal, like the above `legs four` as opposed to Andrew's `platform four`, which would be just saying the numeral.

Comment: The train now arriving on platform four...

Comment: well, yeah, but I think here it is only saying the numeral out loud - and I'm talking about expressing quantity

Comment: *"He called for his pipe, and he called for his bowl, and he called for his fiddlers three."* But that's poetry from several centuries ago.

Comment: Ocean's Eleven.

Comment: Sif of the Warriors Three: http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Warriors_Three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, quantity is expressed before the noun. Any other use in usual circumstances would be considered intentionally aberrant or just incorrect.

In poetry or other writing which allows license, it could be done. For example, googling *my sisters three* will reveal a book title and lines from a poem (My older sister - of my sisters three); all others show the normal usage (My sister's three year old twins are running around...)